# for loop in Object Oriented Php

Tags: php

By using the Concept of object oriented Php Here is the block of code to be executed based on a given condition .The counter was supposed to count from 0 1 2 3 4 5 till it reaches the specified number... but here it is not working as it was intended

//conside the code below

```
class Counter{
    public $number;
    public function setCounter($number){
        $this->number = $number;
    for($this->number ;$this->number < 10 ; $this-> number ++){
       }
    }
    public function getCounter(){
        echo $this->number;
    }
}
$counter= new Counter();
$counter->setCounter(0);
$counter->getCounter();
```

Comment: Please don't spam irrelevant language tags. This has nothing to do with Java, JavaScript, Python, or even CSS.

Comment: ok@VLAZ anyways help to get the correct answer

Comment: You echo the counter after the loop runs to 10 so you get 10.  What do you expect?  If you want each number you'll need to echo inside the loop.

Comment: so which is the correct code?@AbraCadaver

Comment: [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) about for-loops gives plenty of examples

Comment: What should the value be when you call `$counter->getCounter();`?

Comment: @mikerojas    it outputs  10 instead of counting from 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do, but as a learning exercise, you only `echo` the number after the loop has executed so it is `10`.  To get each number you need to `echo` it in the loop.  One of these, though this is probably not the best pattern overall:

Either get rid of `getCounter`:

```
class Counter{
    public $number;
    public function setCounter($number){
        $this->number = $number;
        for($this->number ;$this->number < 10 ; $this-> number ++){
            echo $this->number;
        }
    }
}        
$counter= new Counter();
$counter->setCounter(0);
```

Or call it in the loop:

```
class Counter{
    public $number;
    public function setCounter($number){
        $this->number = $number;
        for($this->number ;$this->number < 10 ; $this-> number ++){
            $this->getCounter();
        }
    }
    public function getCounter(){
        echo $this->number;
    }
}
$counter= new Counter();
$counter->setCounter(0);
```

And/or add a `count` method:

```
class Counter{
    public $number;
    public function setCounter($number){
        $this->number = $number;
    }
    public function getCounter(){
        echo $this->number;
    }
    public function count() {
        for($this->number ;$this->number < 10 ; $this-> number ++){
            $this->getCounter();
        }
    }
}        
$counter= new Counter();
$counter->setCounter(0);
$counter->count();
```

Comment: when and how to use the variable public $number? cause i see it has nothing to do with the code above

Comment: I just forgot to copy it, edited...Though it should work without it, it is created automatically when you do `$this->number = $number;`

Comment: ouk bro @ AbraCadaver